# CSS текст налезает на другой текст

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при создании дива, у меня текст начал налезать на другой текст, при сжатии экрана (у меня 19 дюймов, открывается нормально, а вот на маленьких экрана текст лезет на другой текст), вот как должно быть на всех экрана:

[СКРИН 1](http://f3.s.qip.ru/3GS55jng.png)

А вот так открывается сейчас на маленьких экранах:

[СКРИН 2](http://f4.s.qip.ru/3GS55jnh.png)

```css
    .text_russia {
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     position: absolute;
     margin-left: 38%;
     color: #0088cc;
     top: 53%;
    }
    .email_russia {
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     position: absolute;
     margin-left: 38%;
     color: #0088cc;
     top: 72%;
    }
    .phone_russia {
     font-size: 21px;
     font-weight: bold;
     white-space: nowrap;
     position: absolute;
     margin-left: 26%;
     top: 58%;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="phone_russia">
        +7 777 555 666 222
       </div>
       <div class="text_russia">
        <a href="/info/contact" class="no-dec other-text-info">Звонок по России бесплатный</a>
       </div>
       <div class="email_russia">
        <a href="mailto:test" class="no-dec other-text-info">test@test.com</a>
       </div>
```

Comment: Что, никто не знает в чем проблема? Могу подробнее объяснить и скинуть еще кусок кода.

Comment: На этом форуме, чаще не отвечают по причине того, что или вопрос не интересен, или он задан так, что не особо хочеться разбираться.

Вот взял я ваш код и почему-то сам, а не вы, [закидываю на fiddle][1]. Вижу, что нет ничего и близко с тем, что вы показывали на скринах. Значит, мне придётся вам задавать "тридцать три" дополнительных вопроса или самому подгонять под требуемый результат. Вот желания разбираться и поубавилось.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/W3hLs/

Comment: left стоит 38% вот и оно залезло на маленьком экране. Резиновый сайт?
Увеличьте лефт до 50 там где 38, будет на правой половине. Вообще уберите проценты, ну с другой стороны при такой верстке все равно будет налазить,меняйте все, в общем.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 с пикселями делал, не сработало.

Нет близко потому, что на него влияют другие дивы, которые не влияют на его положение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите `min-width` в стилях CSS, и используйте величины в `px` а не `%`.

Comment: @Astat пробовал, не получается :(

Comment: на jsfiddle забросьте код

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 http://jsfiddle.net/Z2uC3/